# Unambiguous geometry terms for specific kinds of circular symmetry

Tags: geometry, terminology, symmetry, mirror-symmetry

I'm writing a paper on asymmetries in the human visual system and want to ensure that I am using correct/unambiguous terminology to describe the asymmetries in question. Unfortunately, I've had trouble finding a clear description of the various terms. Below is an example of the kinds of things I want to unambiguously state—are these terms colloquial or are there precise meanings to each?

Example: a star shape (⭐️) is clearly asymmetric in some ways and symmetric in others. Specifically:

1. it has a *radial symmetry* along five radial lines because each side of the relevant line is a reflection of the other;
2. it has *radial asymmetries* along every other line because the two sides of the relevant radial line aren't reflections of each other;
3. it is *circularly asymmetric* because there is at least one radial asymmetry;
4. however, a circle, a cone, and a 2D Gaussian are all *circularly symmetric* because each possesses no radial asymmetries (assuming we are talking about radial lines in the x-y plane).

Are these statements correct and unambiguous? Are there other terms related to these that are clearer?